# MySQL select yesterday's date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

If I have a date like this:

```
'2013-03-25'
```

And I want to write a MySQL query with `WHERE` is "yesterday", how do I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL selecting yesterday's date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146828/mysql-selecting-yesterdays-date)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A simple way to get yesterday's date is to use [`subdate()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate) function:

```
subdate(currentDate, 1)
```

Answer (score 27):

This should do it:

```
WHERE `date` = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: What if it's a minute earlier than the current time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. Can you clarify please?

Comment: Should that be `curdate()`, not `now()`? AFAIK, your code will only work if the time-of-day matches exactly

Comment: I'm assuming a column type of `date` which may not be true. So your suggestion is a good one and is safer so I have edited my answer to use it.

Comment: If `date` is a `DateTime`, it should be `DATE(date) = CURDATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for:

```
DATE_ADD(date_column, INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

I always have to refer to a code snippet to wrap my head around this again.

It's customary to store datetimes in UTC in the database.  But usually, when generating reports, the times need to be adjusted for a specific timezone.

Here's the snippet I use to show selecting yesterday, adjusted for Pacific time:

```
SET @date_start = DATE_SUB((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 8 HOUR);
SET @date_end = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR);

SELECT
    projects.token,
    projects.created_at as 'UTC created_at',
    DATE_SUB(projects.created_at, INTERVAL 8 HOUR) as 'Pacific created_at'
FROM
    projects
WHERE
    projects.created_at BETWEEN @date_start AND @date_end;
```

**Note:** I set the variables in the snippet so it's easier to look at.  When I write the final query, I usually don't use the variables.